# iOS Localization of large files like movies

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, localization

I am creating a new iOS project, where I have to include a video in my app. We need to access this video also in offline mode - so I need to include it as video file in my project.
The question - what is the best practice for such large file localization? App will be in at least 7 languages and I can not decide - include video in 7 languages which would dramatically change size of app or include it only in English and localize other stuff? Probably someone knows - if my phone language is for example Spanish and I download localizable app - does this app include videos in all languages or only in my selected?

Any answer will be appropriated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Localized app will always include all the files. When you change your language settings in iOS, localized stuff will appear in that language.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about it. Then why should I clean before reinstalling app (at least in simulator) and remove previously installed app? I also tested it now - changed the language settings in simulator, closed app and relaunched - it used settings, that were used during first run of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something nifty with bundling the video and audio separated. You could then play the correct audio for each localization. The same could be done with subtitles.

Most optimized way would be to not bundle any video in the application and just allow the users to download the video for the current localization from within the app. That's what I think.

Comment: Bundle video separately - it breaks down first start of app when we plan to play this video on first launch. At the same time - separate video and audio sounds quite tricky solution, still we also have different videos, not only sounds for each language.

Answer (score 0):

A single video can have multiple audio streams. So you can simply create one video with multiple audio streams. Audio is general smaller compared to video. So should not hurt as much. User can then select the audio langauage [or program can preselect based on some preference] to play it out.

Almost all container formats can contain more than 1 audio stream. [Almost all, definitely mp4 which is what I guess you are using.]

EDIT: You can possibly also have two files. One with half the languages which are the most common and one with other half which are less common to reduce some size.